# bootstrap tooltip at the end of countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a countdown on a page that will display "Please wait" when it reaches 0. I would like to display a bootstrap tooltip with some text.

The "Please wait" text is either generated by the javascript below or if the user reloads the page (and that the database has been updated yet after the countdown - I have a script running every two minutes to update the database status).

When I reload the page the tooltip is well displayed:

[image]

The produced code is:

```
<div title="" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="It can take up to two minutes...">
<div data-countdown="Please wait">Please wait</div>
```

But if the "Please wait" comes from the javascript, the tooltip is not well displayed:

[image]

In that case the produced code is:

```
<div data-countdown="2016-05-14 16:44:21">
<div title="It can take up to two minutes..." data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip">Please wait</div>
</div>
```

This is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');   
        $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
            if (event.elapsed) {
                $this.html(event.strftime('<?php echo '<div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="'.$this->lang->line('wait_tooltip').'">'.$this->lang->line('pleasewait').'</div>';?>'));
            }
            else {
              $this.html(event.strftime('%D <?php echo $this->lang->line('days');?> %H:%M:%S'));
            }
        });
 });
</script>
```

How can I make the tooltip displayed correctly from the javascript as well?

Comment: You should initialize manually the tooltips if you generate their markup after the page is loaded.

Comment: could you please provide a bit more guidance? What should I initialize? I tried adding `<div class="tooltip top" role="tooltip">  <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>` but it didn't help

Comment: You need to initialize the newly-created tooltips like `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

micmia's opinion should be right, let me try to clarify a bit more.
Firstly, as stated in bootstrap document, `For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in, meaning you must initialize them yourself.` Also, I tried out on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qbfz6zcu/ , it appears to be true that `tooltip`s won't work without explicit initialization(note the init js codes are commented, if you uncomment them, tooltip will show). Not sure how your page-reload-and-tooltip-works part works.
And here's a brief clarification on what the *initialization* does: bootstrap's tooltip works by adding an eventListener to the "please wait" part so when you hover on them, event triggered and you see the tooltip. I guess there's some init code in your page you didn't notice, so anyway, **if you modify your dom some time after the page's loaded, you'll have to *initialize* again after every time you do so, cause the newly added html elements won't have the event listener to show tooltips**

Comment: I was first trying to initialize the tooltip before modifying the dom. I simply moved the initialization after the page gets modified and it works!